# How do you set FSAA/FXAA settings per applications in NVIDIA Settings

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-settings

<strike>I am trying to set FSAA on Minecraft with NVIDIA Settings (Application Profiles) but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried other applications as well and it doesn't seem to do anything.</strike> Please tell me if there is anything wrong with my configuration.

Edit: I found out FSAA doesn't work on Minecraft even if it is enabled globally. FXAA works on Minecraft when it's enabled globally but messes with *Google Chrome. I wonder if there is a way to set FXAA settings per application.

[image: My NVIDIA Profile for Minecraft]

- System Information:
- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- GPU: NVIDIA RTX 3060 Ti
- NVIDIA Driver Version: 525.85.05

Note: If I enable FSAA/FXAA for all applications they start to bug out. (*Google Chrome becomes a white window.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by doing the following,

1. Open **NVIDIA Settings**
2. Click **Antialiasing Settings**
3. Press **Enable FXAA**
4. Click **Application Profiles**
5. Click **Profiles**
6. Click on the **Green Plus Button**
7. Make sure to have the same settings as the picture:
   [image]
8. Click on the **Gear Icon**
9. Click on the **Green Plus Button**
10. Make sure you have the same settings as the picture:
    [image]
11. Click on the **Green Arrow Button**
12. Click **Rules**
13. Click on the **Green Plus Button**
14. Make sure you have the same settings as the picture:
    [image]
15. Click on the **Gear Icon**
16. Click on the **Green Plus Button**
17. Make sure you have the same settings as the picture.
    [image]
18. Click on the **Gear Icon**
19. Verify that the `GLAllowFXAAUsage=true` rule is on top of the `GLAllowFXAAUsage=false` rule.

[image]

20. Click on the **Green Arrow Button**
21. Quit **NVIDIA Settings**